# I'm trying to retrive data from database which was entered by user and result will be in a pdf file

Tags: python, django-3.0

I'm trying to retrive data from database which was entered by user and result will be in a pdf file but unfortunately not succeeded. can any one help me..

this is my first time asking question on stackoverflow , even i have tried to add my code it showing some error.

code is in comments

model.py

```
 class Doners(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

view.py

```
def donateddetails(request,*args, **kwargs):
     data = {
         'name' : {{Doners.name}},
         'desc' : {{Doners.desc}}
            }
     pdf = render_to_pdf('donateddetails.html', data)
     return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

utils.py

```
  from io import BytesIO
  from django.http import HttpResponse
  from django.template.loader import get_template
  from xhtml2pdf import pisa

   def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
        template = get_template(template_src)
        html  = template.render(context_dict)
        result = BytesIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
        if not pdf.err:
            return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(),
                           content_type='application/pdf')
        return None
```

Comment: Please, put your code in your question, not in comment.

Comment: kindly check my code dude